# Multi channel isolated barrier: how to tell if inputs are isolated from each other?

Tags: isolation

I've been trying to figure out if in multi-channel isolated barriers the inputs are isolated from each other. For instance consider the following 2 channel isolated loop repeater:

http://files.pepperl-fuchs.com/selector_files/navi/productInfo/edb/072149_eng.pdf

The datasheet says nothing about inputs being isolated from each other but there is this image on page 2:

[image]

Does this image mean the inputs are isolated from each other (as well as the outputs) or not?

Comment: I guess this depends on your definition of isolation. For all practical purposes I would say they are isolated. As long as you stay within the datasheet specs. They could have diodes at the input to shunt over voltage to ground or something like that. This you couldn't measure with a ohm meter.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, but sometimes these parts may share common connections inside. If you have one on hand, see if you can measure any resistance between the two channels, if it's too high to measure, they may be isolated - but not necessarily to the same level as the input and output side, it may be fine, but avoid high voltages between channels until you know for sure